# php-gd installed but fails to function in centos 7 (php 7.3 version)

Tags: gd, php-gd

I am trying to install moodle but it shows php-gd extension is missing/should be enabled.
However the gd is already installed and latest, and when I command `php -v` I get the following error as indicated below.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so (/lib64/libraqm.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_ft_font_set_load_flags), /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.17 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2020 08:29:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.17, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.17, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I did a lot of editing but I could not find a single solution. Please help

Comment: what is the output of this command: php -m | grep gd

Comment: How did you install the gd module?

Comment: here is the ouput for rpm -qa|grep gd and i used yum install php-gdgdm-gdm-3.8.4-27.el7.x86_64
gd-last-2.3.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
libgdither-0.6-8.el7.x86_64
php-gd-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64
gdisk-0.8.6-4.el7.x86_64
gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
libs-3.8.4-27.el7.x86_64
gd-devel-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64
gupnp-igd-0.2.2-3.el7.x86_64
gdb-7.6.1-51.el7.x86_64
gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64
pulseaudio-gdm-hooks-3.0-22.el7.x86_64
cgdcbxd-1.0.2-5.el7.x86_64
php73-php-gd-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64
libgdata-0.13.3-4.el7.x86_64
gdk-pixbuf2-2.28.2-4.el7.x86_64 @DavidHlavati

Comment: if i run php -m | grep gd  //I GET ////
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so (/lib64/libraqm.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_ft_font_set_load_flags)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Did you install all of the listed packages?

Comment: I would reinstall the gd package using this command: "yum install gd gd-devel php-gd"
Then restart the httpd service: sudo systemctl restart httpd
Finally check the result: php -m | grep gd

Comment: What are other packages? In Moodle - other extensions are all installed including soap, mbstring, zip etc and works fine

Comment: with yum install gd gd-devel php-gd" , it says installed and latest as follows ////Package gd-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gd-devel-2.0.35-26.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php-gd-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Do you know where is the gd.so located? The error message above says that it tries to load it from the /usr/lib64/php/modules, but it cant find it there. So maybe the issue is that it was installed to a different directory. Do you have multiple php cli versions installed?

Comment: you can list the installation locations of the package files with the -ql parameter if you install the package with the rpm command

Comment: the file is the on /usr/lib64/php/modules as indicated

Comment: I ran into this today in an un-updated copy of Centos 7. gd and gd-devel were up-to-date, but `harfbuzz` wasn't and needed to be manually updated to support that symbol.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem:

```
# php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so (/lib64/libraqm.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_ft_font_set_load_flags)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.32 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2020 07:33:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.32, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

A quick search in google told me that `hb_ft_font_set_load_flags` comes from HarfBuzz  (https://harfbuzz.github.io/harfbuzz-hb-ft.html).

I installed it with `yum install harfbuzz`, and after that the warning is gone:

```
php --version
PHP 7.2.32 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2020 07:33:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.32, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
yum install libraqm-devel
```

```
[root@* ~]# yum provides '*/libraqm.so*'
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
libraqm-0.7.0-4.el7.x86_64 : Complex Textlayout Library
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libraqm.so.0.700.0
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libraqm.so.0



libraqm-devel-0.7.0-4.el7.x86_64 : Complex Textlayout Library
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libraqm.so


[root@* ~]# ll /usr/lib64/libraqm.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Jul 20 23:20 /usr/lib64/libraqm.so -> libraqm.so.0.700.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Jul 18 19:00 /usr/lib64/libraqm.so.0 -> libraqm.so.0.700.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19792 Jan 11  2020 /usr/lib64/libraqm.so.0.700.0
```

`libraqm.so` provided by `libraqm-devel`.

Install `libraqm-devel` will also install freetype and harfbuzz, which provide `hb_ft_font_set_load_flags`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it